# Is there any point of doing any good deeds?

Tags: sin, jannah, day-of-judgement

On day of judgement if you have backbitten someone your good deeds will given to that person or if you don't have good deeds you will take his evil deeds.  We all know everyone backbite, it's difficult to be free from it or any other sins.  Also there is no guarantee if you have a lot of good deeds you will enter Jannah so is there any point of doing good deeds?  I am not telling anyone to stop doing good deeds, just asking a question to increase my knowledge.

Comment: Well, you yourself said in your question how evil deeds will be exchanged with good deeds. So, we must do more good deeds to counteract the sins we are also doing.

Comment: 1. Do you do good deeds, MrJannah? If yes what is your own reason? 2. What do you mean by good deeds?

Comment: @truthcures I do good deeds sometimes, I do Islamic good deeds because I do want to enter Jannah, I mean good deeds like salah, dhikr, fasting, helping others etc, I think The Z has answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Purpose of doing good deeds**

114. Perform the prayer at the borders of the day, and during the approaches of the night. The good deeds **take away the bad deeds**. This is a reminder for **those** who remember.
115. And be patient. God **will not waste the reward** of the virtuous.

Surah 11

---

6. Whoever strives, strives only for himself. God is Independent of the beings.
7. Those who believe **and do righteous deeds**—We will remit their sins, and We will **reward** them according to the best of what they used to do.

Surah 29

**Bad deeds may be erased**

5. This is the ordinance of God, which He sent down to you. Whoever fears God—He **will remit his sins**, and will amplify his reward.

Surah 65

Answer (score 0):

Brother, doing good deeds is very important because it may erase bad deeds, and increase your position in jannah, in shaa Allah. You'll (likely) regret the moment you missed the chance to do a good deed, because those will very likely change your life *ETERNALLY*. Know what's light on the tongue, yet heavy on the scale on the Day of the Judgment? Dhikr, and the best Dhikr is the Holy Quran.

And Allah knows best.